# Insert image into Slidify presentation from local file

Tags: markdown, rstudio, slidify

I'm new to Slidify (and markdown) and am trying to figure out how to insert images into my slides (from a local file).  Provided below is the path I am using to my local file, but the image is coming up with a box and question mark.  I'm guessing this is a quick fix -- any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
![width](/Users/beperron/Desktop/UM.png)
```

Also, if you have any reference to a slidify cheat sheet, please pass that along -- it would be greatly appreciated! Thx

Comment: Try to use relative paths. So try moving `UM.png` to the same folder as your Rmd document and you can then do `![width]("UM.png")`

Comment: As @Ramnath mentioned, the relative path is almost certainly correct. You certainly don't want quotes around the filename in this syntax though!

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem, local directory does not work but a online image address will work. I searched and no relutions.

Good news is that if you save the presentation as a web file, the image will show in the end in the html file after you open it in some browser.

I think the problem is that knit does not "complie" (or something like that) the local file available as a online image before you save it as web page.